# How to read all image from folder and save image with same name in other folder python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, glob

I have images in the folder my file name is **Doc0006.Row1City.jpg**. the following code save the image after cropping with the same name but I want to save the image like this **Doc0006.Row1City_augment.jpg** where I can change in this code

```
import os.path
import glob
import cv2
def convertjpg(jpgfile,outdir):
    
    src = cv2.imread(jpgfile, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    try:
        dst = src[100:500, 200:600] 
        #dst = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        print(dst.shape)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(jpgfile)), dst)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
for jpgfile in glob.glob(r'/home/hammad/thyroid/data/Hammad/Hammad/HH_Scans_Prediction/7104220_576_F/OriginalScan/*.png'):
    convertjpg(jpgfile,r"/home/hammad/thyroid/data/Hammad/Hammad/HH_Scans_Prediction/7104220_576_F/Cropped/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this line in your code:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(jpgfile)), dst)
```

by

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(jpgfile).replace('.jpg', '_augment.jpg')), dst)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have one more question. I have the image Doc0006.Row1City.jpg and its ground truth in txt file Doc0006.Row1City.gt.txt                                                                                 After augmentation Doc0006.Row1City_augment.jpg  my file name is this I want to copy the same ground truth for all the augmented file. How can I processed it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(jpgfile).replace(".jpg", "_augment.jpg")), dst)
```

Explanation: The default name with which it was saving as you mentioned was `Doc0006.Row1City.jpg`. Now the `replace` function will replace the `.jpg` part of your file name with `_augment.jpg`. This will save the file with the desired name of `Doc0006.Row1City_augment.jpg`.